# Enable [FE][cHashIncludePageId] in TYPO3 7.6?

Tags: typo3-7.6.x

In TYPO3 status report. i am getting this type of error `Cache Flooding Protection is disabled. Please enable [FE][cHashIncludePageId] in the Install Tool`.

So, I have set this value `[FE][cHashIncludePageId]= true` in TYPO3 install tools.... Now TYPO3 status report all configuration is Ok.

But getting frontend error like below.

```
Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1467983513: ID parameter needs to be passed for the cHash calculation! As a temporary not recommended workaround, you can set $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['cHashIncludePageId'] to false to avoid this error.
```

Thanks!